# I want nc!nuke #channel for bot delete all messages (dont channel, only messages on channel)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

whos have code on that maybe?

````
async def nuke(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
    if channel == None: 
        await ctx.send("You did not mention a channel!")
        return

    nuke_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=channel.name)

    if nuke_channel is not None:
        new_channel = await nuke_channel.clone(reason="Has been Nuked!")
        await nuke_channel.delete()
        await new_channel.send("THIS CHANNEL HAS BEEN NUKED!")
        await ctx.send("Nuked the Channel sucessfully!")

    else:
        await ctx.send(f"No channel named {channel.name} was found!")```
````

Comment: Why do you `discord.utils.get()` the channel again if you already have the channel?

Comment: So for whatever reason there's a 14-day limit on deleting messages as the comments below have discussed. it may be better to copy all of the data about the channel (name, channel group, channel description, role settings), delete the existing channel entirely, and re-create it using the information collected before its deletion.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the `discord.TextChannel.purge()` function.

```py
channel # discord.TextChannel object (most likely the argument)
await channel.purge(limit=100) # Purge a certain amount of messages. You can choose
```

See the `purge()` function [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge)

Comment: i dont want purge only write nc!nuke and bot delete all messages in channel

Comment: Deleting all the messages in the channel is purging @Alvesok

Comment: @Alvesok You can only delete a max. of 100 at a time.

Comment: @Dominik You can delete all the messages as you can. They just have to be less than 14 days old.

Comment: @12944qwerty A channel can literally have about 2000+ message in only 1 hour. Your command won't help.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav Yes, but it's the only way to delete all the messages without deleting the channel.

Comment: OP said that they do not want to delete the channel, only wants to delete the messages

Comment: "*Doing this will only work for messages 14 days old and under and you can't delete above 100 messages at a time.*" Everything else would thrown an error. @BhavyadeepYadav

Comment: @12944qwerty Who said you can't delete the channel? Let me answer and you will see.

Comment: @Dominik Nope! The command can purge any number of messages. I have tried deleting `1000` messages too.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav OP said. Look at the edit history and title of question. "_Don't channel, only messages on channel_"

Comment: @Dominik It can delete more than 100 messages at a time. I don't know where you found that quote. (The first part is right though)

Comment: This solution is correct though. `purge` = Messages are deleted. The channel will still remain.

Comment: @12944qwerty Looks like the answer I looked at was outdated.